# How to find Android tablet or mobile in Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui, phonegap

I need set android device smart phone portrait only? **window.isTablet** is find the mobile or tablet only, so I need to set screen lock orientation and write code too.

Comment: Since you are using Onsen UI, have a look at `ons.ready` and `ons.orientation` utilities to handle this easily.

Comment: Thanks @FranDios for your suggestion..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Cordova Screen Orientation Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) we fixed.

In app.js

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    if (window.innerHeight <= 736 || window.innerWidth <= 736) {
        screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
    } else {
        screen.orientation.unlock('portrait');
    }
});

window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    if (window.innerHeight <= 736 || window.innerWidth <= 736) {
        screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
    } else {
        screen.orientation.unlock('portrait');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow `potrait` mode **only**, then add -

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
```

inside `<widget>` tag in `config.xml` in your project folder.

You may not be able to find `Tablet or Mobile version` as far as this [Cordova Device](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/) plugin is considered.

You can get the following [properties](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/) -

> - device.cordova  //version of Cordova running on the device.
> - device.model   //name of the device's model or product
> - device.platform  //device's operating system name
> - device.uuid
> - device.version
> - device.manufacturer  //the device's manufacturer.
> - device.isVirtual  //device is virtual(emulated) or real
> - device.serial

Answer (score 0):

Use following code,

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
if (window.innerHeight <= 736 || window.innerWidth <= 736) {
    screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
} else {
    screen.orientation.unlock('portrait');
}
});
```